# want to link crew Assignment to above tables given I'm getting an error How to solve this error?

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE Route(
RouteNo VARCHAR(10),
Origin VARCHAR(30),
Destination VARCHAR(30),
DepartureTime VARCHAR(15),
SerialNo VARCHAR(5),
ArrivalTime VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY(RouteNo) );

CREATE TABLE Employee(
EmployeeID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(30),
Phone NUMBER,
JobTitle VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID) );



CREATE TABLE Flight(
SerialNo VARCHAR(5),
RouteNo VARCHAR(5),
FlightDate DATE,
ActualTD VARCHAR(10),
ActualTA VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY(SerialNo, RouteNo, FlightDate),
FOREIGN KEY(RouteNo) REFERENCES Route(RouteNo),
FOREIGN KEY(SerialNo) REFERENCES Airplane(SerialNo) ); -- does Airplane table exists ? 

CREATE TABLE CrewAssigment(
EmployeeID VARCHAR(5),
RouteNo VARCHAR(5),
FlightDate DATE,
Role VARCHAR(45),
Hours INT,
PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID, RouteNo, FlightDate),
FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY(RouteNo) REFERENCES Route(RouteNo),
FOREIGN KEY(FlightDate) REFERENCES Flight(FlightDate) );

Select * from CrewAssignment
```

This is my code where I'm getting an error in the CrewAssignment table and above are the tables where the foreign key is referenced from.

Error report -
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
catalog view

Comment: One thing noted: `RouteNo varchar(10)` vs `RouteNo varchar(5)` ?

Answer (score 0):

A few objections.

- This is clearly an Oracle question, not MySQL. How do I know? `ORA-02270` is an Oracle database error code; pay attention to tags you use.
- You should use `VARCHAR2` datatype instead of `VARCHAR`. Why? Oracle recommends so.
- `create table flight` fails first as it references the `airplane` table, and it doesn't exist yet (at least, not in code you posted)
- error you're complaining about is due to `create table crewassignment`. One of its foreign keys references the `flight` table:

  ```
  FOREIGN KEY(flightdate) REFERENCES flight(flightdate)
  ```

  but `flight`'s primary key is composite, made up of 3 columns:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY(serialno,
              routeno,
              flightdate)
  ```

  which means that you can't create that foreign key.

So, what to do? No idea, I don't know *rules* responsible for such a data model. Either modify primary key of the `flight` table, or modify foreign key constraint of the `crewassingment` table.

Perhaps you could add a new column to `flight` table (made up of a sequence (or identity column, if your database version supports it) and then let the `crewassignment` table reference *that* primary key. Columns you currently use as a primary key (`serialno, routeno, flightdate`) would then switch to **unique** key.